# Need help in customizing logging with log4j

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I'm trying to setup a customized logging mechanism on my application but had no luck on it. What I have in mind is to create a separate log files for each consumer of my web service.

To have an idea about it:

Consumer sends a HTTP request to my application. It would contain a specific request header variable;value would be "consumer1" for example. Now what I'm trying to do is put all the log entry on a log file that would be named "consumer1_webservice.log".

What I have done so far is filter the header values and stored it on a log4j.MDC class upon authentication.

I had also created a custom RollingFileAppender that has specific requirements to my need but what I can't figure out is how would I be able to modify log4j to suite my need? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some code how you have done it?

Comment: That sounds like a bad plan. You may run out of file handlers , incur performance problems while writing to so many file handles.Add the consumer1 string as a prefix in each log statement. and when you are examining a log you can grep on that word

Comment: I haven't actually done any coding yet, I'm still doing research on how I could actually write the logs on a file per consumer

Performance wise, it wouldn't be an issue for now. Number of consumer product would only be limited to 5